# How can I insert sys.anydataset into table in a procedure of oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a function in ORACLE that return sys.anydataset type. I want to insert that result into a table, that's ok. but if I wanna do same thing in a procedure I will get this error:

> "ora-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"

this is my query:

```
insert into mytable (
    select a,b
    from table(myfunction())
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the table DDL and a function that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I can't because that function is in ORE and probably you haven't that.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by running my insert script in a "execute immediate" command in this way:

```
execute immediate('insert into mytable (
                                        select a,b
                                        from table(myfunction())
                                       )
                  ')
```